# JDeveloper Deployment to WLS IPv6 issue

Tags: oracle-adf

I have already written some ADF web app. Now I want to deploy it on Weblogic server. 
I installed and configured almost everything. 
For example:
Weblogic, 
ADF runtime

Deploy is finished fine to WLS.

```
[04:16:37 PM] [Deployer:149194]Operation 'deploy' on application 'Application1_ViewController_webapp' has succeeded on 'Server'
[04:16:37 PM] Application Deployed Successfully.
[04:16:37 PM] The following URL context root(s) were defined and can be used as a starting point to test your application:
[04:16:37 PM] http://[2001:0:9d38:953c:200e:224f:f5ff:f983]:7203/MyApp
[04:16:37 PM] Elapsed time for deployment:  37 seconds
[04:16:37 PM] ----  Deployment finished.  ----
```

But in my case: test URL is  http://[2001:0:9d38:953c:200e:224f:f5ff:f983]:7203/MyApp
I think URL is: IPv6

But i want IPv4 URL. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your server has a IPv4 address, and you haven't changed the WLS settings, then you will have a IPv4 access already.

It reports the address as IPv6 since most software will default to using IPv6 if available.